# How to make Material UI Pagination responsive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

may I ask whether there is a way to make the material-ui Pagination responsive??
From the official API doc, there are only 3 sizes optional, but I want to make it responsive as my other elements.

```
<Pagination count={10} size="small" />
<Pagination count={10} />
<Pagination count={10} size="large" />
```

I want to make it sth like size="3vw", but it seems not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry @Nafis, I am not using makeStyles in my small react project... So I didn't try your solution, but appreciate your answer!

On the other hand, I kind of worked it out with overwrite the css of material UI which you can find out from developer tool.

This time I just need to make it more compact when the it is in a small screen, so I did something like below:

```
@media screen and (max-width:512px) {

.css-rppfq7-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiPaginationItem-root{
    margin: 0 0;
    min-width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 17.5px;
  }

}
```

Hopefully it could provide you some hints if you face similar difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

try `Mui-selected`.
like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>({
  root: {
      '& .Mui-selected': {
        width: 'somethin',
        height:'any size you need',
       },
  }),
);
const classes = useStyles();
return <Pagination
            count={10} 
            className={classes.root} 
            renderItem={(item)=> <PaginationItem {...item} 
                           classes={{selected:classes.selected}} />}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

In Material UI v5 We can modify the pagination item height and width property using the styled component for mobile and desktop screen

```
import { Pagination as MuiPagination, styled } from "@mui/material";

const StyledPagination = styled(MuiPagination)(({ theme }) => ({
  "& .MuiPaginationItem-root": {
    [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
      height: "1.8rem",
      width: "1.8rem"
    }
  }
}));
```